# Table with a sequence:

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I can generate a table:

```
Table[{i, If[i == 4, 1, i + 1]}, {i, 4}]
```

and the output is

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}
```

however, if I want to make i>4 lets say 12

```
Table[{i, If[i == 4, 1, i + 1]}, {i, 12}]
```

the output is now

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 
  10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}}
```

is there any way I can get the following output instead,

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}, {9, 
  10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 9}}
```

Comment: You leave us guessing what is the rule. What don't you spell it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want it to be `i-3` when `i` is divisible by 4:

`Table[{i, If[Mod[i, 4] == 0, i - 3, i + 1]}, {i, 12}]`

Answer (score 8):

```
Table[{i, If[Divisible[i, 4], i - 3, i + 1]}, {i, 1, 12}]
```

You might also think about this as a permutation.

```
Transpose[
  {Range@12, 
   Permute[Range@12, Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}, {5, 8, 7, 6}, {9, 12, 11, 10}}]]}]
```

You could also see this as applying a transformation to sublists.

```
Transpose[
  {Range@12, 
   Flatten[BlockMap[RotateLeft, Range@12, 4]]}]
```

Or you could construct it from a base pattern.

```
Flatten[
  Table[
    k + SubsetMap[RotateLeft, Table[{i, i}, {i, 4}], {All, -1}], 
    {k, 0, 8, 4}], 
  1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Many great answers already.
I would say that this is a good case where you could use `ReplaceAll` and `Condition` together:

```
Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 12}] /. {x_, y_} /; Mod[x, 4] == 0 -> {x, x - 3}

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}, {9, 
  10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 9}}*)
```

You can modify your **rule** easily as well to suit whatever you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ Partition[Range[12], 4], 1]
```

> `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 5}, {9,  10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 9}}`

Answer (score 2):

One method among many is to use

```
Table[{i, 4*Quotient[i-1, 4] + Mod[i+1, 4, 1]}, {i, 12}]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, 
 {7, 8}, {8, 5}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 9}} *)
```